# multiple input with same name in php

Tags: php, html, input, radio-button

I have 4 inputs as such

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_1" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_2" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_3" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_4" />
```

when the first any of the 3 first are checked, I can't get it back in my `$_POST` variable
How can it be ?

Comment: Since (a) The name ends in `[]` so PHP will express it as an array and (b) They are radio buttons so you can't check more than one at a time anyway: There shouldn't be any problems with that. You'll need to provide a *complete*, reduced test case for people to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Do you use any javascript before submitting?

Comment: @MarkusHofmann yes I do, I use it to add checked class (otherwise it wouldn't be possible since I am using dynamic generated checkbox )

Comment: @user1611830 The problem might originate from the javascript. Double check that. You could create a jsFiddle to show the JS. Also add a e.g. `var_dump()` of the _$_POST_, so we can see the data you receive after the form was submitted.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann ok it was a javascript issue. Thanks so much !

Comment: @user1611830 Nice to hear that you got it working now! Added my answer, so you can mark it as accepted to finalize this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML looks fine and should work as intended.

As you told me in the comments that you're using JavaScript to dynamically generate the form, double check the script to make sure that it is not interrupting the form submission in any way.

Tell me if you got it working. Else we'll try to further investigate :-)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's radio buttons. Not checkboxes. You need to use type="checkbox" or all names change to 'newsletter_to'.

Can you show your $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="newsletter_to[]" value="newsletter_to_4" />

<?php

$NewsLetter_to=$_POST["newletter_to"]

?>
```